# No rep for accepted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

The FAQ for WebApps doesn't mention any effect on rep of accepted answers.

> Here's how it works: if you post a good question or helpful answer, it will be voted up by your peers: you gain  10 reputation points for an answer, and  5 for a question. If you post something that's off topic or incorrect, it will be voted down: you lose  2 reputation points. You can earn up to  200 reputation per day, but no more. (Note that votes for any posts marked "community wiki" do not generate reputation.)

I'm assuming this is because (as shown in the other questions) this site is based on StackApps.

Comment: Why the tag FAQ? I assume it will eventually be used for FAQ questions as on SO and unless confirmed by the mods I see this as a bug.

Answer (score 6):

The meta site gets rep from your account on the WebApps site, so you don't earn rep on meta. You do still gain badges though.